# Google Drive macOS client can't dowload files inside mounted dmg virtual drive

Tags: data-synchronization, mount, dmg, google

I'm trying to let Google Drive client to sync files inside mounted dmg.
I've added the folder (mounted dmg) to Google Drive client for backup.
Everything works fine: upload of new files from my machine, deletion of files on my machine are propagated to online Google Drive and deletion of files from web are propagated to my machine.
But when I create a new file from Google Drive Web inside the folder, Google Drive Desktop client can't create file inside the mounted dmg: it always return 'not enough disk space' .. my free space is more than 200Gbyte and the issue happen with 2 files of 100KB each.
The dmg file was created for read and write, I can create files inside dmg on my machine but it seems Google Drive can't ...

Has anyone experienced same problem ?

Thank You

Comment: Title & body don't match. Title says 'can't download' body says 'can't create'. Having said that, it doesn't surprise me at all that GDrive can't work correctly with Apple's .dmg format.

Comment: Sorry, You're right ... basically Google Drive can't sync new files from cloud (download) inside a mounted dmg .. it can sync to cloud (upload) and it can remove deleted files from cloud without any issues ... but it can't sync from cloud (download). I think it detect wrong virtual disk (dmg) size or it detect it's full...

Comment: I think you're over-estimating what an online [non-Apple] sync solution is capable of. It sees 'a file' - if the 'last updated' flag changes, it will re-sync the entire file. Hoping it is smart enough to open it, know it's an expandable Mac disk image & deal with it accordingly I think is a bridge too far.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue: Google Desktop Client can't sync correctly with a small (100MB) mounted dmg virtual drive ... with a 1GB virtual drive everything works correctly.